# Pairwise distinct subsequence

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Suppose there is an infinite sequence $S_n = (s_1, s_2, \dots )$ generated by a finite set of numbers $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Given a number $m$ such that $m < n$, the subsequence $(s_i, s_{i+1}, \dots, s_{i + m -1} )$ is pairwise distinct. In addition, the set of connective subsequences are different. That is $\{s_i, s_{i+1}, \dots, s_{i + m -1}\}$ and $\{s_{i+1}, s_{i+2}, \dots, s_{i + m}\}$ are different sets.

For instance, we have $S_n = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, \dots )$. If we choose $m = 4$, then any subsequence of length 4 satisfies the criteria.

My question is given an $m$, is there a way to determine the smallest $n$ and is there any pseudo-random algorithm to generate such sequence? Thanks.